# How to override method in class that implements interface

Tags: java, oop

I have an interface `Readable` and I have class `ReadableImpl` that implements it.

```
public interface Readable {
    void doThis();
    void doThat();
} 

public class ReadableImpl implements Readable {
    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("do this");
    }

    public void doThat() {
        System.out.println("do that");
    }
}
```

What should I do if I want to override method `doThis()`? Should I implement `Readable` in another class?

Edit: I don't want to edit class `ReadableImpl`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here?  Are there two behaviors for `doThis()` which you have in mind, or something else?

Comment: You have implemented `doThis()` in `ReadableImpl`. If you want to override the method it has to be in other class extending `ReadableImpl`. If you want to override in the class, you have to get your basics correct. Within a class its `overloading` which has its constraints.

Comment: You have already overridden (implemented I should say), haven't you?

Comment: @Ran Should I create another class `public class ReadableImpl2 extends ReadableImpl implements Readable `?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you might find it acceptable to _overload_ `doThis` in the same class, and, e.g., just change the method signature for the other behavior.

Comment: @user25963 yes! no need to implement `Readable` interface again.

Comment: Your question seems very unclear as it doesn't tell where do you want to override the method. If you want to just implement one method `doThis()` then you have to make this class abstract and then create a subclass to this which will implement remaining abstract methods. As per the code you have given since `Readable` is interface and `ReadableImpl` is implementing `Readable`, hence it's already override the method < or u can say implementing>.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are implementing (some call it overriding) in `ReadableImpl`. If you want to override again it has to be within a class which extends `ReadableImpl` and need not implement `Readable` again. Simply,

```
public class ReadableImpl2 extends ReadableImpl {
    @override
    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("do this overriden");
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree with @Ran about the solution provided, but I disagree about the explanation:  "_implementing_" **is not** "_overriding_" , as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745422/implementing-a-method-of-interface-is-overriding-or-not-in-java)

Comment: @HJuls2 indeed, as you can override a method with an abstract method without an implementation…

Comment: @Holger Yes, what you're saying is allowed,but honestly,  I can't see an actual use of that scenario...

Comment: @HJuls2 well, it might be that the inherited implementation is not suitable for a specific contract and the subclasses must override it with a different implementation. Sometimes, an abstract method overrides another abstract method just to have a documentation comment containing a description of the extended contract.

Answer (score 0):

Your example already overrides it! 
You can just override `doThis()` in class `ReadableImpl` directly.

As long as you implement an interface in your class, you can override any method in the interface by simply writing the exact same method name/return type/parameter in that class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need to do, and the level of compatibility with `ReadableImpl` that you need.

You can subclass `ReadableImpl` and override `doThis`:

```
public class ReadableImpl2 extends ReadableImpl {
    @override
    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("do this 2");
    }
}
```

If you don't have access to the instantiation, you can use a proxy:

```
public class ReadableProxy implements Readable {
    private final Readable delegate;

    public ReadableProxy(Readable delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("do this proxy");
    }

    public void doThat() {
        delegate.doThat();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question

> What should I do if I want to override method doThis()? Should I
>   implement Readable in another class?

I think is not really clear because of some mix in operations naming related to extends/implements. So let me try to answer you question explaining everything around using you example:

```
public interface Readable {
    void doThis();
    void doThat();
}
```

Having such interface you can `implement` its methods in Class of you choice by using `implements` key word

```
public class ReadableImpl implements Readable {
    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("do this");
    }

    public void doThat() {
        System.out.println("do that");
    }
}
```

Now if you would like to `override` this method, the only way to do it is to create new class which `extends` `ReadableImpl`, because `to override` means to **change the functionality of the *parent class* method** in *child class*:

```
public class ReadableImplChild extends ReadableImpl{

        @Override
        public void doThis() {
            System.out.println("do this more specific way");
        }

        @Override
        public void doThat() {
            System.out.println("do that more specific way");
        }
    }
```

But if you want a completely different way of handling this, that `ReadableImpl` is handling the `Readable` interface methods, you should create **a new class** which will `implement` this interface **introducing new functionality**

```
 public class ReadableTotallyDifferentImpl implements Readable {
        public void doThis() {
            System.out.println("do this totally another way");
        }

        public void doThat() {
            System.out.println("do that totally another way");
        }
    }
```

You can ( I know that you do not want, but you can) `overload` a method. And it means **to create new version of the same function which differs** only by number and/or types of the method parameters

```
public class ReadableImpl implements Readable {
    public void doThis() {
        System.out.println("do this");
    }

    public void doThat() {
        System.out.println("do that");
    }

    /**
     * this is funciton overloading
     */
    public void doThat(String userSpecific) {
        System.out.println("do that for:" + userSpecific);
    }
}
```

According to you question:

> What should I do if I want to override method doThis()?

Well, it depends:

1. **If you want an slightly different functionality** (I would say, more specific way of doing something) --> you should **create a
   child class**, and **override its methods**
2. **If you want completely different realization of this interface**, you should **go with new class and implement it differently**
3. **If you really have to use** `ReadableImpl` class, but **you want this method to work differently**, you can either **overload it**,
   or **change its implementation**